# In SqlAlchemy how to share function between different table ORM

Tags: sqlalchemy

I wrote some table ORM in SqlAlchemy, and I want to share common functionality between them, this is my table ORM:

```
class RetailCampaignTemp(Base, Serialize, PrimaryField):
    __tablename__ = 'retail_campaign_temp'
    clicks = Column(INTEGER(11))
    id = Column(INTEGER(11), primary_key=True)
```

Here are my custom functions:

```
class Serialize(object):
    def Serialize(self):
        return {c: getattr(self, c) for c in inspect(self).attrs.keys()}

class PrimaryField(object):

    @declared_attr
    def GetPrimaryField(cls):
        yield from (column for column in cls.columns if column.primary_key)
```

When I call `RetailCampaignTemp.GetPrimaryField()` it say `'generator' object is not callable`, what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit here is the `@declared_attr` decorator, which creates a class property, not a class method - that is, the expression `RetailCampaignTemp.GetPrimaryField` is already running the function body and returning the resulting generator, and `RetailCampaignTemp.GetPrimaryField()` is trying to call this generator.

This decorator is designed to be used to dynamically create sqlalchemy mapping/table declarations, e.g. by returning a relationship. From your example code it doesn't look like this is the case, so is there any reason you're not just using python's builtin `@classmethod` instead? This would make your call `RetailCampaignTemp.GetPrimaryField()` valid.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I was not familiar with @classmethod , I will read up on it